# A childen's book with a rhyme about a badger's home

Tags: identification-request

I remember a few details about three children's books I read in elementary school in the USA, presumably borrowed from the school library instead of the local library, because I remember them in connection with a school I attended in November 1961 to June 1962.

And it is possible that maybe those details I remember were in two books or one book instead of three.

One detail I remember is lines from a possibly longer poem or song:

> A thousand years maybe,
> This place's been tenented
> by folk of badger ancestry.

European badgers dig large dens or setts with many entrances, tunnels, and chambers, occupied by groups of badgers for generations - a sett in Germany is supposed to be over ten thousand years old.

So naturally there are children's stories where badgers live in underground houses which are otherwise just like human homes.

And so I guess those lines came from a children's book with one or more anthropomorphic badger characters living in a complex underground home, somewhat like a large Hobbit hole, and one where their family had lived for centuries.

Can anyone identify that book?

Added Jan. 30,2024.  A separate memory I have is reading a children's brook where a badger had an elaborate underground home built like a human structure (similar to, but not, Badger's house in The Wind in the Willows) and I thought that book had a title like *Badger's Wood* or *Who Goes to the Wood*.  Ayshe's answer shows that the rhyme I remember comes from *Who Goes to the Wood* by Fay Inchfawn, 1942.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned on [previous question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/a-childrens-book-with-a-rhyme-naming-cities-in-western-england), I searched on archive.org and [*Who Goes to the Wood*](https://archive.org/details/whogoestowood00inch/) (1942) by Fay Inchfawn came up.
[Page 52](https://archive.org/details/whogoestowood00inch/page/52/mode/2up) has a very similar excerpt to what you you remember:

> A thousand years maybe,
> This house was tenanted by folk
> Of Badger ancestry.