# A children's book with a Beast in a forest

Tags: identification-request

I remember a few details about three children's books I read in elementary school in the USA, presumably borrowed from the school library instead of the local library, because I remember them in connection with a school I attended in November 1961 to June 1962.

And it is possible that maybe those details I remember were in two books or one book instead of three.

And I remember one books in which there was a forest, and I think that a human boy lived in the forest or visited it.  And I think that the forest was inhabited by talking animals.

And all I remember about the plot was the climax.  A group of characters, including the boy and maybe other humans and maybe some of the talking animals, joined together to drive a Beast out of the forest.  As I remember it was a big furry beast, and probably not of a scientifically recognized species.

Anyway the characters teamed up against the Beast because it was "evil".  And I wonder why animals, if any were part of the mob, would consider a Beast more "evil" than some of the animals.  In any temperate zone forest there would probably be one or more of the following, depending on how wild it was: weasels, and foxes, and badgers, and wildcats, and wolves, and bears, which would eat some of the other animals.  So I find it a little implausible that members of predator species  would join with members of their prey species to attack a Beast which they all agreed was "evil".  What could the Beast do which members of prey species would consider more evil than killing and eating them and grounds for joining with members of predator species to fight?

I guess in a story with talking animals they could behave in any way the writer wanted.

Does anyone recognize this book?

Comment: How large were these books (both in thickness and cover area)? What did the covers look like? Were there illustrations, and if so, in what style? Please [edit] each question if you remember more details such as these

Comment: I assume this isn't [The Minpins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Minpins)?

Comment: @RAnd al'Thor.  Since The Minipins was published about 30 years after I remember reading that book, I guess your assumption is correct.

Comment: @Bobble  I associate that library with rather small and thin hardbound books, possibly with slick board or plastic covers, each in one color.  Since Ayshe's answers show that two of the books I asked about were both Who Goes to the Wood by Fay Inchfawn, and since the photos of it I can find on the internet look different from that description, I don't know how accurate that impression of the books in that library is.

Answer (score 1):

[Who goes to the wood](https://archive.org/details/whogoestowood00inch/) by Fay Inchfawn (posted as possible candidate on previous questions [1](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/a-childrens-book-with-a-rhyme-naming-cities-in-western-england) and [2](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26137/a-childens-book-with-a-rhyme-about-a-badgers-home)) has a Reddy Fox character badgers want to get rid of, so it is possible that you are indeed remembering details from one book.